# Main difference between Shared memory and Distributed memory

Tags: memory, multiprocessing, distributed, shared, cpu-architecture

I'm a bit confused between about the difference between *shared memory* and *distributed memory*. Can you clarify?

1. Is shared memory for one processor and distributed for many (for network)?
2. Why do we need distributed memory, if we have shared memory?

Comment: 2. Shared memory is on one host, distributed memory is on many hosts. 3. Distributed memory is needed when you share memory across many hosts.

Answer (score 25):

#### Short answer

*Shared memory* and *distributed memory* are low-level programming abstractions that are used with certain types of parallel programming.  Shared memory allows multiple processing elements to share the same location in memory (that is to see each others reads and writes) without any other special directives, while distributed memory requires explicit commands to transfer data from one processing element to another.

#### Detailed answer

There are two issues to consider regarding the terms *shared memory* and *distributed memory*.  One is what do these mean as programming abstractions, and the other is what do they mean in terms of how the hardware is actually implemented.

In the past there were true **shared memory** cache-coherent multiprocessor systems.  The systems communicated with each other and with shared main memory over a shared bus.  This meant that any access from any processor to main memory would have equal latency.  Today these types of systems are not manufactured.  Instead there are various point-to-point links between processing elements and memory elements (this is the reason [for non-uniform memory access, or NUMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_memory_access)).  However, the idea of communicating directly through memory remains a useful programming abstraction.  So in many systems this is handled by the hardware and the programmer does not need to insert any special directives.  Some common programming techniques that use these abstractions are [OpenMP](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/) and [Pthreads](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/).

**Distributed memory** has traditionally been associated with processors performing computation on local memory and then once it using explicit messages  to transfer data with remote processors.  This adds complexity for the programmer, but simplifies the hardware implementation because the system no longer has to maintain the illusion that all memory is actually shared.  This type of programming has traditionally been used with supercomputers that have hundreds or thousands of processing elements.  A commonly used technique is [MPI](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/mpi/).

However, supercomputers are not the only systems with distributed memory.  Another example is [GPGPU](http://gpgpu.org/) programming which is available for many desktop and laptop systems sold today.  Both [CUDA](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-zone) and [OpenCL](https://www.khronos.org/opencl/) require the programmer to explicitly manage sharing between the CPU and the GPU (or other accelerator in the case of OpenCL).  This is largely because when GPU programming started the GPU and CPU memory was separated by the PCI bus which has a very long latency compared to performing computation on the locally attached memory. So the programming models were developed assuming that the memory was separate (or distributed) and communication between the two processing elements (CPU and GPU) required explicit communication.  Now that many systems have GPU and CPU elements on the same die [there are proposals](http://www.hsafoundation.com/) to allow GPGPU programming to have an interface that is more like shared memory.

Comment: When is it recommended to use distributed memory systems and when is it recommended to use shared memory systems?

Answer (score 5):

In modern x86 terms, for example, all the CPUs in one physical computer share memory.  e.g. 4-socket system with four 18-core CPUs.  Each CPU has its own memory controllers, but they talk to each other so all the CPUs are part of one coherency domain.  The system is NUMA shared memory, not distributed.

A room full of these machines form a distributed-memory cluster which communicates by sending messages over a network.

Practical considerations are one major reasons for distributed memory: it's impractical to have thousands or millions of CPU cores sharing the same memory with any kind of coherency semantics that make it worth calling it shared memory.